# Вывод строки / столбца из матрицы

Tags: c#, winforms, матрицы

Приведённый ниже код выводит из массива строку/столбец, что задаются пользователем вручную. Однако вывод осуществляется в виде матрицы, а нужно чтобы выводился одномерный массив(грубо говоря, во второй таблице только строка, а в третьей только столбец), как это сделать??

```
       {
            int[,] m = new int[DGV_A.RowCount, DGV_A.ColumnCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < DGV_A.RowCount; i=i+1)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < DGV_A.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    m[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_A[j, i].Value);
                }
            }
            //
            int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); // Ввод числа для получения строки p
            int q1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);  // Ввод числа для получения столбца q
            //Вывод массива X
            for (int j = 0; j < DGV_A.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                DGV_X[j, p1].Value = DGV_A[j, p1].Value;
            }
            //Вывод массива Y
            for (int i = 0; i < DGV_A.RowCount; i++)
            {
                DGV_Y[q1, i].Value = DGV_A[q1, i].Value;
            }
```

[image: ааа]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас DGV_A, DGV_X и DGV_Y - это три одинаковых контрола, созданных в дизайнере форм.

Как я понял, Вам нужно преопределить кол-во строк и столбцов в контролах DGV_X и DGV_Y: в одном делаем 1 строку, в другом - 1 столбец.

Эти контролы - это стандартный WinForm'овский DataGridView. При создании таких контролов студия склоняет вас к тому, чтобы назначить им то, что называется DataSource. При этом размер контрола начинает зависеть от того, сколько данных есть в data source. Это называется data binding, и, с одной стороны, это удобно, так как не надо напрямую привзяывать "такую то ячейку к такому то элементу матрицы", а, с другой стороны, это лишает Вас гибкости.

Поэтому хорошо бы для DGV_X и DGV_Y или назначить другие DataSource, или отказаться от использования DataSource и "все делать руками"

Если пойти по первому пути - то вам одновременно ст матрицей надо будет завести две "фиктивные", "вырожденные" матрицы: одна будет копией одного столбца основной матрицы, вторая - копией строки основнйо матрицы. И уже эти две матрицы назначить в качестве DаtaSource для DGV_X и DGV_Y.

Если работать "вручную", то надо погуглить по словами data grid view unbound mode - скорее всего, первые же 1-2 примера дадут Вам общую картину.

Надеюсь, моё объяснение позволит Вам разобраться дальше.

Comment: Я уже предлагал `DataTable` и `BindingList`, автор игнорит эти способы взаимодействия с DGV.

Comment: @S.H. слишком долгое объяснение, мне нужно что-то по проще(заранее извиняюсь, если покажусь наглым), но с примером

Comment: @Orion вы задаете размер X на Y, задайте X на 1, затем поменяйте `DGV_X[j, p1].Value = `на `DGV_X[j, 0].Value =`. Сойдет за пример?

Comment: @aepot, да, помогло, спасибо